# Java FileWriter not writing to file

Tags: java, json, filewriter, is-empty

I'm creating an app which requires to write a file for every user (in JSON format).

The app successfully creates the file, But it's empty. In the code I added a finer output to see how the converted JSON String looks like, and I noticed that it's complete (it contains everything, so the conversion is ok). But the string isn't present in the file.

```
//create a new FileWriter C:/.../42.guser
        FileWriter writer = null;

        //for every User
        for(int i=0; i<users.size(); i++) {

            try {
                File f = new File(Users.usersDir.getPath()+"/"+i+".guser");

                //Create new file
                f.createNewFile();

                writer = new FileWriter(f);

                //convert to json and write to file. Here we get the object with KEY = keys[i].
                String stringedUsr = gson.toJson(users.get(keys[i]));

                logger.finer("Converted user: \""+stringedUsr+"\""); //Output seems ok

                //Write (NOT WORKING)
                writer.write(stringedUsr);

                logger.fine("Wrote updated user \""+keys[i]+"\" to file "+f.getCanonicalPath());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                FAILS++;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        //End of for
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: i gave to the app all the necessary Permissions. No `AccessControlExceptions`

Comment: try `flush()` method, also close the writer on completion

Comment: Just closing it should be fine. That will flush.

Comment: @AxelMontini No because it wont call flush or close ;-)

Comment: That whole re-assignment business is a code smell. Why don't you declare `writer` inside of the block where you use it and assign it on declaration? Always keep variable scopes as small as possible. (That alone won't help you here, of course, you need to `finally` close).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all think about closing your writer. 
When closing, it should `flush()` your data first (as mentioned in the doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html))

You can also `flush()` manually.